# Unable to completely uninstall SOAPUI

Tags: windows, soapui, uninstallation, program-files

when uninstalling the SOAPUI from windows 10 or windows 7 it will uninstall the application but the smart bear folder in c:/program files is not removed.
I am uninstalling soapui with the uninstaller.exe in the smartbear folder.
can anybody help me with any suggestions as to why the smart bear folder is not being deleted when we use the uninstaller

Comment: Hey, this is very common, many uninstallers keep the installation folder. I don't know the particular reason, by I guess that there are remaining files (sometimes hidden).

Comment: Can you look into the directory to find what is left? May be log files which can be removed manually.

Comment: there are .install4j,jre,error,uninstall in that folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, any software installation, it keeps track of the file being installed. And the same files gets removed on *uninstallation*.

However, some softwares installation creates new files during that process. Apart from that, if software is used, some log files are created too.

But, when the software is uninstalled, it leaves the files those files that did not track (it may think that those are user files) and leaves them as is.

Since you know now that, those are files are not persisted by you, remove the remaining files safely.

The above mentioned is not just for this software, applicable for any software installed using installer, IMO.