# shell script to uninstall smartbear directory

Tags: bash, shell, soapui, uninstallation, program-files

when i uninstall soapui using the uninstaller it doesn't delete the smart bear folder in c/program files.
Can somebody help me with a shell script to remove smart bear folder after uninstalling SOAPUI using the uninstaller.exe

Comment: I am not sure if the task is clear to us to try to help. You mentioned bash, shell, script, yet uninstaller.exe is a Windows style program name.I mean, on what platform should be the final solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to completely uninstall SOAPUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46812192/unable-to-completely-uninstall-soapui)